# How can I calculate medium font-size to px value?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

The CSS [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-fonts-3-20180920/#propdef-font-size) defines the `font-size` property in the following way:

> This property indicates the desired height of glyphs from the font.
> For scalable fonts, the font-size is a scale factor applied to the EM
> unit of the font. (Note that certain glyphs may bleed outside their EM
> box.) For non-scalable fonts, the font-size is converted into absolute
> units and matched against the declared ‘font-size’ of the font, using
> the same absolute coordinate space for both of the matched values.

Furthermore, it prescribes a user agent to compute font sizes for such values as `[ xx-small | x-small | small | medium | large | x-large | xx-large ]` where `medium` represents 1 scale factor.

In view of a declared `font-size` value is ultimately computed as a length in absolute units, I wonder can we say for sure what value in CSS `px` would `medium` amount to? Of course, I'm aware every font has a bunch of its metrics and there are notorious issues related to the fact different OS/browsers apply different of them. However, having font information like this

[image]

can I exactly work out `medium` in `px`, let's say, for Windows+Chrome or Mac OS+Chrome? Are these formulas specified somewhere or for each font the output is always kind of surprise?

Answer (score 0):

The end game with fonts is to serve the user with their prefered font size. Browsers will default to specific values until, or if, the user changes the default. The last thing you want to do is over-ride a users preference.

With all due respect, it seems like you might be splitting hairs here. You should probably concentrate on how your font sizes look in relation to each other (i.e. headings versus paragraphs) instead of drilling down to a pixel.

Comment: Having the fixed user preferences on font size we nevertheless result in different font lengths for different fonts when the same `font-size` value is applied. Not being aware of how a browser uses font metrics it's hard to predict the relative view of two elements with different fonts.